# MVVM WPF Tutorials

Tags: c#, data-binding, xaml, architecture, mvvm

I have now some experience in wpf and mvvm. But there is the whole structure(architecture) already written.

Like TestView.xaml and TestViewModel.cs Where those files al already binded.

I wonna learn more from the architecture. How to write the base class, Business access layer , ...

Can somebody gave me some good tutorials. Where i can find some information. To get an "technical  architect".

Comment: This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) by Josh Smith should give you what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here. So you are trying to find MVVM specific tutorials or overall architecture tuts?

Comment: Both MVVM and overall architecture.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Visual Studio 2010 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate, I would consider the interactive tutorial made by Karl Shifflett that can be found here : [In the Box](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/).

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this article: [**Layered Architecture**](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Architecture%20-%20Get%20The%20Big%20Picture&referringTitle=Home). It shows a concrete structure for WPF Rich Client applications. It also shows how the **Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)** pattern fits into the layers.

Furthermore, the codeplex project contains sample applications that show how this architecture can be applied.